# ASP.NET Expression <%= ...%> gives error CS 1518 when used with C# expression

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors

I've been poking at this all morning and I can't seem to find the way to do this.

I have a web app that has to show a tooltip on one of its div-s. The tooltip's contents come from some DB querying

< div style="height: 10px; clear: both;" title="<%=dbCount %>  device(s) with version <%=devVersion %> in this group">

This works fine.

If I try replacing the `<%=dbCount %>` with an expression:

```
< div style="height: 10px; clear: both;" title="<%=dbCount > 0 ? ""+dbCount : "No " %>  device(s) with version <%=devVersion %> in this group">
```

then on PageLoad I get an exception CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum.

It doesn't matter how I structure the expression, if I put parenthesis or not, if I use String.Format or ternary expression - any sort of expression, besides using the variable name only, causes the error.

I tried replacing <%= with <%# and tried <% Response.Write(dbCount>0 ? "some" : "none") %> and I get the same error. This is the only line in the aspx I'm editing so the error is due to it, not elsewhere on the page.

I could use an <% if(...){  construct but then the designer is having trouble with finding the closing div and I don't want to pollute the source with too much junk, I'd rather keep the original version.

Do you know why is the compiler error showing up and how can I prevent it and use the output expression <%= devCount>0?"some":"none" %>?

Comment: Have you tried a helper function to return what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write code like that.
Aspx files only support that for backward compatibility.

If you really really must do it, Write only public properties that way.

Refer: [Embeded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0)

> Embedded code blocks are supported in ASP.NET Web pages primarily to
>   preserve backward compatibility with older ASP technology. In general,
>   using embedded code blocks for complex programming logic is not a best
>   practice, because when the code is mixed on the page with markup, it
>   can be difficult to debug and maintain. In addition, because the code
>   is executed only during the page's render phase, you have
>   substantially less flexibility than with code-behind or script-block
>   code in scoping your code to the appropriate stage of page processing.

That said, the link does show you how to properly use embeded code.

If you really must do it this way, use Response.Write.

```
< div style="height: 10px; clear: both;" title="<% 
  { 
    string countMessage = dbCount > 0 ? ""+dbCount : "No "; 
    Response.Write(countMessage ); 
  }
%>  device(s) with version <%=devVersion %> in this group">
```

Answer (score 0):

All these variants are running ok here, among the C# samples I include the case you mentioned which is also running fine:

In VB.NET

MarkUp:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="<%If dbCount = 1 Then%><%="22"%><%Else%><%="55"%><% End If%>">   
    <%=dbCount.ToString()%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Codebehind:

```
Partial Class varIn
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public dbCount As Short = 0

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

         If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
           dbCount = 1
         End If

    End Sub    
End Class
```

In C#

MarkUp:

```
<div id="<%if (dbCount == 1) { %><%="22"%><%;}else{%><%="55"%><%;}%>">   
<%=dbCount.ToString()%>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div id="<%=dbCount > 0 ? ""+dbCount : "No " %>">   
<%=dbCount.ToString()%>
</div>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

    public short dbCount;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dbCount = 1;            

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test web app and your code (<%=dbCount > 0 ? ""+dbCount : "No " %>) works fine (I'm assuming that "< div" is a mistype).  I'm assuming that dbCount is an int and devVersion is a string.  Is there something else going on?  Is dbCount a public property that calls a method?  Is it a public variable?

What is dbCount in your app?